# How to sort a list of places according to current location

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort a list of places which are saved in my firebase database with their longitude and latitude
i have the current location saved the the variable Latlng
i succeded in showing the current lat long and every place's lat long in the logcat but I couldn't find the algorithm that sort these places
here is my code

```
private List<Pharmacie> sortPharmacies(List<Pharmacie> mPhList) {
    double currentlong = latLng.longitude;
    double currentlat = latLng.latitude;
    System.out.println("currentLat: "+currentlat+" ,currentLong: "+currentlong);
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                mPhList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Pharmacie pharmacie = snapshot.getValue(Pharmacie.class);
                    System.out.println(pharmacie);
                    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 = snapshot.child("Location");
                    ;
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2 : dataSnapshot1.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println(dataSnapshot2);
                         //   Location location = dataSnapshot2.getValue(Location.class);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ClosestPharmacy.this, "NO RESULT!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return mPhList;
}
```

here is the Pharmacie table

[image]

here is the output of this code

```
/System.out: currentLat: 36.8747844 ,currentLong: 7.7170403
I/System.out: com.memoire.getmymed.Model.Pharmacie@544210c
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = Lat, value = 8.7415141 }
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = Long, value = 37.8977585 }
I/System.out: com.memoire.getmymed.Model.Pharmacie@b5bea55
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = Lat, value = 7.7469683 }
    DataSnapshot { key = Long, value = 36.894459 }
I/System.out: com.memoire.getmymed.Model.Pharmacie@a46dc6a
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = Lat, value = 7.7415141 }
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = Long, value = 36.8977585 }
I/System.out: com.memoire.getmymed.Model.Pharmacie@b50555b
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = Lat, value = 7.7238948 }
I/System.out: DataSnapshot { key = Long, value = 36.895591 }
```

Comment: You might want to order the places by distance from a coordinate. It could be done if you order them by the radius with the current location as the centre and finding the distance using the radius http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates

Comment: Data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously, which means that your `return mPhList` runs before the `onDataChange` ever gets called. Any code that needs the data from the database needs to be inside `onDataChange` or be called from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519